# Saving psd to pdf top layer incorrect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've created a design in Photoshop (psd) and am trying to export as a single image to a pdf.  My top layer in my design is an imported image (company logo).  When I save and open the pdf, part of layer 1 (logo) stays on top and part of it falls below other layers. I am a beginner in Photoshop so a descriptive answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you could add a screenshot documenting your problem, I think we may be in better position to help you.

Comment: Are you using Adobe Reader to view the PDF, or some other PDF viewer?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already flattened the PSD, try doing that ('Layer > Flatten Layers') then save PDF.